# How can I find HEAD back in git?

Tags: git, head

Probably due to misuse of `git reset ...`, I lost track of HEAD. I was in a commit which was very behind the last commit I have made, as the following figure showed:

COMMIT n      <-    Expect to go back here
 COMMIT n-1
 ...
 ...            <--  The HEAD is here

And ORIG_HEAD for some reason became the same as HEAD. So how can I get HEAD back to my last commit?

Comment: See if `git reflog` helps you identifying your commit.

Answer (score 0):

Run `git reflog show master` to show the reflog history for master branch.

Comment: Thank you both guys. `git reflog` is exactly the solution.